# used pretraing model in tensorflow .ckpt file

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a ckpt file . I just want to get the weights of the cnn 
that I have trained from a ckpt checkpoint file.?
inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30

```
import tensorflow as tf
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, "inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt")
```

---

```
from tensorflow.core.framework import graph_pb2
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saver_pb2
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
from tensorflow.python.client import session
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.framework import importer
from tensorflow.python.platform import app
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
from tensorflow.python.training import saver as saver_lib
with session.Session() as sess:
var_list = {}
reader =pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader("./inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt")
var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
for key in var_to_shape_map:
    try:
       tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(key + ":0")
    except KeyError:
            continue
    var_list[key] = tensor
    saver = saver_lib.Saver(var_list=var_list)
    saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)
    if initializer_nodes:
       sess.run(initializer_nodes)
```

---

Comment: The code in your question won't work for the same reason that `saver.restore()` doesn't work: there is no graph into which to restore the tensors. What do you want to do with the checkpoint values once they are loaded? You can call `reader.get_tensor(key)` to get the checkpoint value as a NumPy array. You should probably change the body of the `for` loop to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tf.train.Saver.restore()` method only works if you have already built the graph structure (including a set of `tf.Variable` objects) into which the checkpoint will be restored. You have (at least) two options for solving this problem:

1. Use [`tf.train.NewCheckpointReader("inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt")`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/NewCheckpointReader) to open the checkpoint file. You can call the `get_tensor()` method on the returned object to look up a saved variable by name, or the `get_variable_to_shape_map()` method to get a list of the available variables.
2. If you have one, [load a MetaGraph](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph) for the checkpointed mode, which includes the graph structure and a mapping from that graph structure to the variables in the checkpoint.

Comment: [This code in `freeze_graph.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fbad4e056e45a9743f10cec44b2e3c73674fe8ca/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py#L117) uses it in a similar way to how you'd want to use it.

Comment: tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(key + ":0")
not work

Comment: I'd expect that not to work because there are no tensors in your graph. You shouldn't need a session to use `tf.train.NewCheckpointReader` either. If you continue to have problems, add the code that you are trying to run to your question.

Comment: how to put the NumPy array in model tensorflow