# How to remove the last layer from trained model in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to remove the last layer of 'faster_rcnn_nas_lowproposals_coco' model which downloaded from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md.
I know I in Keras we can use model.layers.pop() to remove the last layer.

But I searched in the Internet and there are no equivalent function in tensorflow.
If there are no equivalent function in tensorflow, are there anyone can tell me how to load trained Model zoo by Keras?

Answer (score 26):

You don't need to "pop" a layer, you just have to not load it:

For the example of Mobilenet (but put your downloaded model here) :

```py
model = mobilenet.MobileNet()
x = model.layers[-2].output
```

The first line load the entire model, the second load the outputs of the before the last layer.
You can change `layer[-x]` with `x` being the outputs of the layer you want. So, for loading the model without the last layer, x should be equal to -2.

Then it's possible to use it like this :

```py
x = Dense(256)(x)
predictions = Dense(15, activation = "softmax")(x)
model = Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = predictions)
```

Comment: I have a .ckpt file, for example : model.ckpt file. Could you tell me how to get model = mobilenet.MobileNet() by tensorflow? It so simple in Keras, but in tensorflow I don't really know how to create model = mobilenet.MobileNet().

Comment: You can try the method described here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894104/used-pretraing-model-in-tensorflow-ckpt-file

Comment: Thanks for helping me! But I found the solution: just run file train.py in folder object_detection and set is_training = True. The rest, TF will take care for you.

Comment: Glad that you have found it !

Comment: This is one of the most elegant solutions I found in the internet! model.summary() will not even show the "skipped" layers which is rather nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function
`model.pop()`

Comment: Can you provide more detail on _how_ to use it to solve this specific problem, and why you prefer this approach over the highly-upvoted answer before you?

Comment: Because some times you just need the output from the last second layer while testing on your data to observe some kind of patterns. I am not saying that mine is better than before but I am just providing another way